# How do we get the list of exceptions in Python programmatically?

Tags: python, exception

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exceptions

There is a list of exceptions in Python, and I am trying to make a list (or a set) of the exception names.

I could just simply hard code the names, but is there a way to somehow do this programmatically? Like import the exception class and get all those types of exceptions and put them a list of strings?

Comment: AFAIK: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Comment: It may help to know what you intend to do with that list.  Don't forget that imported modules and users can define their own subclasses of Exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get list of built-in exceptions (not user-defined) you can do this:

```
import builtins

list_of_exception_names = [
    name for name, value in builtins.__dict__.items() 
    if isinstance(value, type) and issubclass(value, BaseException)
]
```

Comment: This code will not work inside a module. `__builtins__` is sometimes a dict rather than a module, in which case the `__builtins__.__dict__` access fails. You should always use the `builtins` or `__builtin__` module rather than the `__builtins__` implementation detail.

Comment: [Here's a demonstration of the failure.](https://repl.it/repls/AwareStudiousUnit)

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for your comments, improved my answer.